# Reset timestamp in dataframe and count up the time

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

So my timestamp in dataframe looks like something like this:

```
    In [18]: df['time'].head(1)
    Out[18]: 2021-10-05 12:00:00.000000+00:00
```

```
    In [19]: df['time'].tail(1)
    Out[19]: 2021-10-07 12:00:00.000000+00:00
```

I want a new column (time_new). There the first timestamp has to be resetted to 0 so starting point is 0.
then it only counts up the hours, seconds and milliseconds. So that at the end there are 48 hours in this case. The following table for illustration.

```
| index     | time                              | time_new      |
|-------    |---------------------------------- |----------     |
| 0         | 2021-10-05 12:00:00.000000+00:00  | 00:00:00.000  |
| 1         | 2021-10-05 13:00:00.000000+00:00  | 01:00:00.000  |
| 2         | 2021-10-05 13:00:00.001000+00:00  | 01:00:00.001  |
| 3         | 2021-10-06 02:00:00.000000+00:00  | 14:00:00.000  |
| 4         | 2021-10-07 12:00:00.000000+00:00  | 48:00:00.000  |
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For timedeltas subtract minimal value of column:

```
df['time_new'] = df['time'].sub(df['time'].min())
```

Or first value of column:

```
df['time_new'] = df['time'].sub(df['time'].iat[0])
```

If format is important use custom function:

```
def format_timedelta(x):
    ts = x.total_seconds()

    hours, remainder = divmod(ts, 3600)
    minutes, seconds = divmod(remainder, 60)
    return ('{:02d}:{:02d}:{:.3f}').format(int(hours), int(minutes), seconds) 

df['time_new'] = df['time'].sub(df['time'].min()).apply(format_timedelta)
print (df)
                              time     time_new
0        2021-10-05 12:00:00+00:00  00:00:0.000
1        2021-10-05 13:00:00+00:00  01:00:0.000
2 2021-10-05 13:00:00.001000+00:00  01:00:0.001
3        2021-10-06 02:00:00+00:00  14:00:0.000
4        2021-10-07 12:00:00+00:00  48:00:0.000
```

For `mean`:

```
avg = df.loc[df['time_new'] <= pd.Timedelta('01:00:00'), 'vibration'].mean()
```

Comment: Little additional question: i want to calculate mean of all values ​​from the first hour (00:00:000 - 01:00:000). how can i select those rows in pandas?

Comment: @AdlerMüller - How looks expected ouput from sample data?

Comment: I junst want the mean of the first n rows where time is equal or less than 1h.
At the moment I use counting values: df['vibration'].iloc[0:1000].mean(). But I want to do it by time (equal or less 1 hour)

Comment: @AdlerMüller `vibration` is another column? Filled by numeric?

Comment: @AdlerMüller - added to answer.